# How to merge multiple skeleton animations into a single file

Tags: three.js, gltf, mixamo

I had my model rigged and animated in MIXAMO(.com), then imported to my scene with GLTF format.

Animation works fine, but I'd like to add more animations like idle, walking and running like in this three.js example (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending).

Mixamo doesn't seem to allow that :-( I can however export multiple files each with different animation fot the same model.

Anyone has a tip how to merge those animations to a single file? I can use any file format or free editor if you recommend one for this.

Comment: You might want to give this tutorial a try: https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/11/06/creating-animated-gltf-characters-with-mixamo-and-blender/

Comment: Thank you, I am still not fully there as Blender is kinda complicated, but this seems to be the way to go.